# Inserting data into Popup with Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

In my Django project, I want to have the institution selection selected from a list, for this I created a model for the institution name and I want the user to enter it as a pop-up window or a list selection for this:
models.py

```
class Institution(models.Model):
institutionName = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.institutionName
```

views.py

```
def getInstitutionName(request):
context = {'institutionName':Institution.objects.all()}
return HttpResponse(context)
```

I created it in the form of html, but I'm having trouble with how to integrate the data I bring here with html. In this process, I want to make a form that includes other entries, only the institution entry in this way. My question on this subject is, what action should I take while printing the data I have brought here to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Django provides the form field [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). When this field of a form is rendered, it will by default generate a `<select>` with `<option>` for each instance in a queryset.

You can either transform this using Javascript, or you can write (or look for) your own widget to use with this field, to generate the HTML you desire.

I'd start by writing a view with such a form and no fancy stuff. When you have it working, then start developing it into the pop-up you seek.

```
class InstitutionSelectForm ( forms.Form):
    institution = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = Institution.objects.all(),
    )
    # other fields

class InstitutionSelectView( FormView):
    form_class = InstitutionSelectView
    template_name = 'myapp/institution_select.html'

    def form_valid( self, form):
        institution_instance = form.cleaned_data['institution']
        # do whatever is called for with this institution and 
        # any other form fields 
        return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse( ...))
```

To start with, a very basic template for rendering a form:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Make it work, inspect the select structure in your browser, and set to work on customizing it.